# Reverse a map that contains another nested map

Tags: java, dictionary, nested, reverse

i would like to know how can I get a new map that is the reversed map of mine?
My actual Map looks like that:

```
centralMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
nestedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

the nestedMap is just created in the put-method..  and to put an element i use the following in the main method:

```
TrueStringMap2D testmap = new TrueStringMap;
testmap.put("Mickey Mouse","Mathematics","1.0");
testmap.put("Mickey Mous","Physics","1.3");
testmap.put("Minnie","Chemistry","2.3");
......
```

now i would like to reverse the map through a method that i named "flipped()" 
i want to change the Keys of the nestedMap to Keys of the centralMap, and vice-versa.. so every "subject" (like mathematics, physics, ..) will have a nestedMap of students and the grades.. how could i do that?

im not allowed to create classes in my TrueString2D.. i just need to copy perhaps the Keys of the centralMap in a list, and those of the nestedMap in another List, and then create a new map HashMap>(); (same as my centralMap) and copy the list of old keys of the nestedMap in the NEW created map (for ex. newCentralMap) as keys, and as value, i'll copy the old keys of the centralMap in the newNestedMap and the values of the newNestedMap are the same as the ones on the old map.. but i dont know exactly how to do that, and if i can copy a list in a map :S

Thankyou verymuch

Comment: `TrueStringMap2D` What is this class? What interface it implements?

Comment: @bpgergo I don't think it implements a Collection interface. It seems its `put()` method just delegates to the inner maps.

Comment: i created it for a 2Dimensional Map.. it just redefine the methods of a normal Map to get these methods for a map with key1, key2, and value for each entry.. i am implementing now TrueString2D :-) i just want a method, which is flipped(), that will reverse the Keys of the centralMap with those of the nestedMap.. should I copy the keySet of the nestedMap in a list an the one of the centralMap too, and then put both of them reversed in a new map? how should i implement this flipped() method that reverses the keys? I hope you understood the problem when you see how i put my entries..

Comment: Thanks ZelelB. You should have posted the source of `TrueStringMap2D` as well. It is hard to answer the question without that. Why don't you use `HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>()` instead of `TrueStringMap2D`?

Comment: its the base of my class TrueString2D.. it creates such a map.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>()` instead of `TrueStringMap2D`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Flip {


    public static Map <String, Map<String, String>> flip(Map <String, Map<String, String>> map){
        Map <String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        for (String key : map.keySet()){
            for (String key2 : map.get(key).keySet()){
                if (!result.containsKey(key2)){
                    result.put(key2, new HashMap<String, String>());
                }

                result.get(key2).put(key, map.get(key).get(key2));
            }
        }


        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map <String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        map.put("Mickey", new HashMap<String, String>());
        map.get("Mickey").put("Physics", "1.1");
        map.get("Mickey").put("Maths", "1.2");

        map.put("Minnie", new HashMap<String, String>());
        map.get("Minnie").put("Physics", "1.1");
        map.get("Minnie").put("Chemistry", "1.3");

        System.out.println(map);

        System.out.println(flip(map));
    }

}
```

the output

```
{Minnie={Physics=1.1, Chemistry=1.3}, Mickey={Maths=1.2, Physics=1.1}}
{Maths={Mickey=1.2}, Physics={Minnie=1.1, Mickey=1.1}, Chemistry={Minnie=1.3}}
```

Comment: thanks bpgergo.. but the retrun type of flipped() must be a Sting2D.. should I will edit the question to put the interface StringMap2D and the class that im implementing, TrueString2D

Comment: 1) Why do you have to use this class: `TrueStringMap2D`? 2) If you really have to use it, you please post the full source of the class.

Comment: Because it is a Homework :-) 
thanks got it ;) i just modified your solution! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use something different for storing your items:

- Guava has a [Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) class that implements the features you are asking for
- If you need even more flexibility, consider an in-memory database

Comment: i'm not allowed to use that.. i must implement my TrueString2D :S

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use maps for this. I would just use a `Collection<PersonGrade>`.

```
class PersonGrade {
   String name;
   String subject;
   Double grade;
}
```

Then when you want to generate a report about "All grades of Mickey Mouse on all subjects" iterate over the Collection and take the objects which fits that criteria. 
I know this could be a bit slow when you are dealing with a huge amount of data. But I would really give it a try.

Comment: im not allowed to create classes in my TrueString2D.. i just need to copy perhaps the Keys of the centralMap in a list, and those of the nestedMap in another List, and then create a new map `HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();` (same as my centralMap) and copy the list of old keys of the nestedMap in the NEW created map (for ex. newCentralMap) as keys, and as value, i'll copy the old  keys of the centralMap in the newNestedMap and the values of the newNestedMap are the same as the ones on the old map.. but i dont know exactly how to do that, and if i can copy a list in a map :S